# how to display years in date select descendingly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

How do you display the year in descending order? At the moment, I have this:

```
<%= f.input :year_started, as: :date, label: "Date started", start_year: Date.today.year - 100, end_year: Date.today.year, discard_day: true, order: [:month, :year], include_blank: true, default: nil, :input_html => { :class => 'profile-date' } %>
```

The drop down year displays like this:

```
1900
1901
1902
....
2015
```

I want the opposite, How do you do it?:

```
2015
2014
2013
....
1900
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it's as simple as swapping start_year and end_year.

Try:

```
<%= f.input :year_started, as: :date, label: "Date started", start_year: Date.today.year, end_year: Date.today.year - 100, discard_day: true, order: [:month, :year], include_blank: true, default: nil, :input_html => { :class => 'profile-date' } %>
```

It's actually in the API-docs: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/date_select#190-Get-year-to-show-in-descending-order-Today-to-192-for-example-

Comment: my bad, simple mistake though.. thanks for spotting!

Comment: @jumbo_siopao, glad I could help.
I saw that you usually don't mark answers  as accepted here at Stack Overflow. 
Read this post in the FAQ on how to accept answers the proper way: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers or this at meta stackexchange: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work